# Docker Swarm - Is it there a Read Only mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

Is it possible to access a remote Docker Swarm and have **Read Only** access?

I was thinking about like a docker context connected to a remote Swarm, while having a RO flag enabled, or something like an environment variable that conditions the docker cli.

Comment: Hello, what did you try so far? Do you have some example to show us?

Comment: So far, I've only researched about this topic, and it lead me to nowhere.
The only way I could imagine to achieve `Read Only Docker Swarm Access` was to create a second layer API that would filter the *not allowed* commands, prompting an error, and send the valid ones to the main Docker API. @XouDo